# Erasing from vector by swapping to the end

Tags: c++, containers

I am wondering why there is no STL function that deletes an element from a vector by swapping it to the end and then removing it. Is there a better data structure than `std::vector` if you don't care about the actual order of elements and still want very fast traversal?

Note that using `std::remove` and `std::erase` is not the same because this is linear time instead of constant time as the order has to be preserved.

Comment: Well, there's a pair of functions you can use together that will do that, so commonly used together that the idiom has [its own wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Comment: But this is not constant time.

Comment: Not with remove and erase because all elements are moved if you delete from the front.

Comment: @Henk The best you can hope for is linear time for a `std::vector` if you wish to maintain a contiguous set of elements *and* preserve order. If order is not important than `std::swap(v[i], std::back())` followed by `v::pop_back()` does exactly what you want.

Comment: My point is that order is not important and the swap solution feels like a hack because it is not a standard function. My intent is not to swap, but to remove efficiently.

Comment: I think the answer is simply that the two line code expresses that operation better than a single function would. It's better to be explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) instead of `std::remove`/`std::remove_if`:

Keep only values greater than 3:

```
std::vector foo{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

foo.erase(std::partition(foo.begin(),
                         foo.end(),
                         [](auto& v) { return v > 3; }
                        ),
          foo.end());
```

Or you could make it similar to the [`std::erase / std::erase_if (std::vector)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) pair that was added in C++20 and return the number of erased elements. I call them `unstable__erase` and `unstable__erase_if`.

```cpp
// Erases all elements that compare equal to value
template<class T, class Alloc, class U>
[[maybe_unused]] constexpr typename std::vector<T,Alloc>::size_type
unstable_erase(std::vector<T,Alloc>& c, const U& value) {
    return unstable_erase_if(c, [&value](auto& v) { return v == value; });
}

// Erases all elements that satisfy the predicate pred
template<class T, class Alloc, class Pred>
[[maybe_unused]] constexpr typename std::vector<T,Alloc>::size_type
unstable_erase_if(std::vector<T,Alloc>& c, Pred pred) {
    using size_type = typename std::vector<T,Alloc>::size_type;

    auto p = std::partition(c.begin(), c.end(), std::not_fn(pred));
    auto count = static_cast<size_type>(std::distance(p, c.end()));
    c.resize(c.size() - count);

    return count;
}
```

---

Since `std::partition` swaps elements I was expecting to be able to improve on the speed by replacing the above

```cpp
    auto p = std::partition(c.begin(), c.end(), std::not_fn(pred));
```

with

```cpp
    auto p = unstable_remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), pred);
```

where I've defined `unstable_remove_if` as below:

```cpp
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate>
constexpr ForwardIt
unstable_remove_if(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p) {
    for(;first != last; ++first) {
        if(p(*first)) { // found one that should be removed

            // find a "last" that should NOT be removed
            while(true) {
                if(--last == first) return last;
                if(not p(*last)) break;          // should not be removed
            }
            *first = std::move(*last);           // move last to first
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

but, to my surprise, running that in https://quick-bench.com/ showed that they performed equally fast for *fundamental* types (up to `long double`).

**Edit:** For larger types, it showed a big improvement (8-16 times as fast for 32 - 64 byte types), so using the `unstable_remove_if` in `unstable_erase_if (std::vector)` is probably the way to go for a generic solution of removing elements matching a certain predicate or value.

Comment: Nice. That works even if your condition is `v % 2 == 0` right? (not just cutting of the tail).

Comment: @wcochran Yeah, the predicate can be whatever.

Comment: This look like a good solution if you could erase multiple elements. If one wants to delete a single element that is for sure in the vector, an unguarded find is more efficient I think.

Comment: @Henk Indeed. Just move-assigning the found element with the last element and resizing as the other answers have shown would probably be optimal in those cases.

Comment: This might also be a better solution to my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65900129/invalidated-iterator-fixing-a-function-with-ub-without-losing-efficiency?noredirect=1#comment116517759_65900129 because deletion happens in a single step.

Comment: @Henk In theory, yes, but I've learned that I need to test my theories about performance before claiming anything :-) I'm still surprised that `std::partition` performed so well for fundamental types when my version didn't have to swap anything. I even tested to actually do an `iter_swap` in my version too and that didn't slow it down :-O

Comment: Mhm, it is not only about practical performance, but also about not doing unnecassry work even if it can be optimized away or does not really matter. In the end, it will always matter somehow if you do strictly less work (here, when types are larger).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Very Nice! But the template parameter should probably be named BidirectionalIt and not ForwardIt. Regarding the practical perfomance, I have a feeling that the better locality for `std::partition` could make the difference. Swapping is pretty cheap for fundamental types, so the savings do not make that much of an impact. But with `std::partition` has both iterators in a similar position at the start while your algo has them at begin and end of the range. Hence partition should behave a bit better with regard to cache lines. With heavier types, the saved swaps will start to dominate

Comment: @n314159 "_locality_" - Yes, I have been thinking about exactly that after I wrote this answer. Perhaps it's possible to redesign `unstable_remove_if` in a clever way to make better use of such practical problems. Perhaps a two-pass algorithm that starts by identifying how many elements that should be removed could open some design doors.

Comment: Yes, I think there are some parts where one can fiddle to obtain a bit better performance for certain cases (trivial types could be more efficiently moved by identifying a range to move and using memcopy). But I do not think that one will get much better performance than your `unstable_remove_if` reliably. The locality will automatically get worse when elements that should be kept are at the end of the vector and there are not that many in total etc.

Comment: Regarding the two-step approach: I think counting is a bit too much overhead (it doubles the number of times the predicate is applied). But maybe the programmer could hint a number of expected elements to be removed and then the algorithm fixes the rest.

Comment: @n314159 "_counting_": i suppose it depends on how cheap the predicate is compared to the move assignment - and that's hard to determine without actually testing it. Well, it's a nice problem to think about. I liked this question because it asks for an algorithm that I guess many would use (when the order isn't important) instead of the idiomatic `erase-remove` or `erase-partition` had it existed in the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

What you want doesn't exist in the standard library but you can write a reusable function for it. This also works for other containers like `std::string` or `std::deque`.

```
template <typename Container>
void unstable_erase(Container &container, typename Container::size_type pos)
{
    container[pos] = std::move(container.back());
    container.pop_back();
}

template <typename Container>
void unstable_erase(Container &container, typename Container::iterator itr)
{
    *itr = std::move(container.back());
    container.pop_back();
}
```

I stole [Ted Lyngmo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65893925/445976) function name, it's better than what I had.

Comment: Plus 1 for `std::move`.

Comment: Nice solution! Maybe an iterator is better than an index here because indices are not that useful anyway when you do not care about the order and everything gets moved all the time.

Comment: @Henk That's doable, I've now written two overloads for an index or iterator.

Comment: @Blastfurnace :-) ... and I was inspired by `std::stable_partition`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't. Vectors are cache-friendly. If by traversal you mean `access all elements`, no other data structure will give as much speed as vector.

The issue with cache is: once you access one element, a few other elements in the same block of memory gets cached also, so when you need to access the next one it will be already in your cache (this will happen many times, for instance: you access one element that is not in your cache and the next 31 or 63[the value will depend on your cache size] gets loaded as a bonus).

If you use something like a set, that is not contiguous, you will lose performance due to a lot of cache misses.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> foo = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

// remove element foo[2] without preserving order in constant time
foo[2] = foo.back();
foo.pop_back();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what number you need to delete, you can use a set for a logarithmic time complexity.
First, you can use the
`s.lower_bound(x)`
function that returns an iterator to the first element >= x in the set s. After, you can do `s.erase(it)`, where it is the iterator. Both of these functions have a time complexity of O(log n), where n is the size of the set.